# How to insert footer in first pages of chapter?

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I am using fancyhdr to make header and footer for pages. In the minimal example the footer is not appearing in the first page of chapter. I want footer to be appear in the first pages of the chapter also. Please help me to do that.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\author{Padmapriya}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{Apurba Paul}
\fancyfoot[LO, RE]{Using fancyhdr}
\title{Using fancyhdr}
\author{Apurba Paul}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{First Chapter}
content of the first title.
\clearpage
content of the next page

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first page of a chapter is typeset using the `plain` pagestyle so that it stands out from other pages. You can modify it with something like:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{Apurba Paul}
\fancyfoot[LO, RE]{Using fancyhdr}}
```

to change the style so your footer is also on the first page of a chapter, leaving the default header unchanged.

Comment: +1 @Chris. For future reference, it might be a good idea to indicate that this is explained in section 7 of the `fancyhdr` manual.